# HTML5 Canvas bitmap masks & drawing bitmaps

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Had hard time finding any info regarding this.
I want to place a main bitmap on canvas (jpg,png) also want to place a bitmap file that is going to perform as a mask of the main bitmap. Further I would wish to continue drawing on this mask-bitmap so that masking will provide sort of eraser feature.

I would be more than happy with links to more reading.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about the erase function, but I can point you to [Canvas-Mask](https://github.com/benbarnett/Canvas-Mask) because I have used it.

It's based on the [Alpha Compositing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) process.  It reads the alpha data from one image and put it into another picture.  Basically the result you it's a merge between the RGB values from the base image and the A values of the mask image.

It's pretty simple but it might be a base for what you want to achieve.